# Assigning a variable to a specific memory location

Tags: c, ram, memory-address

I don't understand how to assign a variable to a Ram place, to be more specific I want to see the result of the following question by writing it myself but I don't know anyways to do it.
I don't want the answer to the question I wrote all of it soo that you can correct me if I can't write this code by myself. And help me a little by saying wich kind of calculation that I need to do.

RAM that has addresses between 0X50 and 0x80 is filled by the value 0x20. I want to determine the value of A at the end of 'C program' segments on the right. In the end, I want to determine A.

```
int main(){
char *C,A=0,B=0x20
C=0x55;
while(B){
B=B+ *C;
C++;
A++;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you need read your own question and rewrite it in the form which can be understood. I have no clue what you are asking for. The code deas not make any sense as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common general-purpose computers, you cannot assign addresses for objects. The addresses are managed for you by other software, and trying to set your own address for an object may interfere with other uses of that memory, may result in a trap if the memory is not mapped in the address space of your process, and may have other adverse consequences.

Assuming this code is for a hypothetical computer in a classroom study, and the computer and the C implementation have typical properties, such as eight-bit `char` (and that `char` is unsigned), then:

- `char *C,A=0,B=0x20` defines `C` to be a pointer to `char`. (This line should have a semicolon to mark its end.)
- `C=0x55` attempts to set `C` to point to the address `0x55`. This is not the correct way to do this because `C` is a pointer, meaning its values are addresses, and `0x55` is a plain integer, not an address. The compiler should warn about this statement. A correct way to do this is to use a cast to convert the integer to a pointer: `C = (char *) 0x55;`.
- After this, the loop starting with `while(B)` will execute as long as `B` is non-zero. Inside the loop, `B=B+ *C;` adds the contents of the memory `C` points to to `B`. Since you tell us the memory in that area is filled with `0x20`, it adds `0x20` to `B`.
- If we assume the computer and the C implementation have typical properties, this will continue with `B` being assigned the value `0x40`, `0x60`, `0x80`, `0xa0`, `0xc0`, and `0xe0`. Then the next addition will produce `0x100`. `0x100` exceeds the eight bits in the `char` `B`, and it will wrap, putting `0x00` in `B`.
- After `B` is set to `0x00`, the `while(B)` loop will end.
- So the loop will execute 7 times (once to set B to `0x40`, then to `0x60`, and so on, until it sets `B` to `0x00`).
- In each iteration, `A` is incremented by one. Since `A` starts at 0 and is incremented 7 times, its final value is 7.

Note: The `C++;` statement changes the value of `C`, changing where it points. In general, this would affect what value is added in the statement `B=B+ *C;`. However, since each byte in that area is filled with the same value, there is no effect; `*C` is always `0x20` in this situation. If the bytes of memory had different values, then changing `C` with `C++;` would change what value is obtained for `*C`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data having the physical address X you need to

```
#define MEM(addr, type)  *(volatile  type *)(addr)


void foo(void)
{
    //write  unsigned int at address 0x1234
    MEM(0x1234, unsigned) = 0x12345689;

    //read char from address 0x4000
    char p = MEM(0x4000, char);
}
```

Accessing the particular addresses is very common in the low level hardware and embedded programming (in the fact there is no other way to access the hardware registers mapped into the address space).